# jQuery jHTMLArea - How to Allow Only Certain HTML Tags?

Tags: jquery, jhtmlarea

Is this possible to limit the HTML only to Bold, Italic, Underline and Breaks in jHTMLArea plugin editor? I'm mostly interested in stripping P tags and using two breaks instead. What I have done in the mean time is:

```
$.fn.stripPTags = function(_str) {
    _str = _str.replace('<p></p>', '');
    _str = _str.replace('<p>', '');
    _str = _str.replace('</p>', '<br /><br/ >');
    return _str;
}
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#txtDefaultHtmlArea_Save').click(function(){
    var _str = $.fn.stripPTags( $('#txtDefaultHtmlArea').htmlarea('toHtmlString') );
    return false;
```

});
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be to customize the toolbar by taking out the HTML button. You would just call the following code in the `$(document).ready(function()`.

```
$("#txtCustomHtmlArea").htmlarea({
    toolbar: ["bold", "italic", "underline", "|", "link", "unlink"]
});
```

The user could enter HTML tags but the editor will sanitize any tags they enter.

Comment: hmm, unfortunately for me, bolds and italics are required. Thx

Comment: The toolbar would allow the user to add bold, italic, underline, and anchor tags but it would add the tags on the back end where the user wouldn't see them.  The user just wouldn't be able to manually enter a `<b>` or more malicious `<script>` in the editor.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks Scott

Comment: Sorry guys, but try to copy and paste from another page that contains for example h1, divs, etc. it will just paste it without removing the undesirable tags. I think we can use the action option to write code to sanitize the code.